# Test a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

This question must be newbie and i know it but i haven't found the answer for some time now. I have implemented a WCF service which i want to test. So when i click open in browser it opened something like [image: this]

So i created the configuration file and the code file and i have input it into my solution in the same folder where the web service lies. When i have put the c# code mentioned above in a button of a web form this [image: happens]
EDIT: This is the output.config that i have mentioned above (i hope that is the client's config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_for_quantity" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:51182/check_for_quantity.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_for_quantity"
                contract="Icheck_for_quantity" name="BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_for_quantity" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

If i run **wcftestservice** the following appears:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could  your post your client's config file please?

Comment: I have edited my original post, hopefully that is that you mention :)

Comment: how did you add a reference to the WCF Service on the client? you also need to make sure that the service is running (I notice you are using either Visual Studio Development server or IIS Express).

Comment: Thanks.  What happens if you point **WcfTestClient.exe** at http://localhost:51182/check_for_quantity.svc?  It should show the **generated** client config.  How does it compare to your client's one?

Comment: Please check the updated first photo. I am pretty newbie at this, so what i have done is. Created the web service, added the service reference from right - click -> add service reference and then irun the web form

Comment: ifi try to run the service from wcftestclient.exe the last photo appears

Comment: As Ahmed mentions, ensure Visual Studio Development/IIS Express is running.  When debugging the "client" web app, ensure VS **also** starts the web service project.  Right-click solution, **Set startup-projects.Multiple**

Comment: _"ifi try to run the service from wcftestclient.exe the last photo appears"_ - thanks. Confirmed, your service is **not** running.  See prior comment. (As a side note, you may want to consider IIS instead of 'Express to avoid these sorts of issues - if you have IIS at your disposal that is)  :)

Comment: I am not sure i got it about the multiple part. The web service and the web form that calls it is in the same project so why the multiple part? (of course the service has been referenced) and iis is running

Comment: _"The web service and the web form that calls it is in the same project"_  -  sounds like you have no `ServiceHost`. You may need to manually host it.  Also, since the client and the server are one in the same in this respect, it's faster not to go over the communications layer but rather call your processing logic directly (i.e. c# classes)

Comment: I've noticed somewhere along the line you've changed your code to use the parameter-less constructor for your WCF client proxy `Icheck_for_quantity`.  Your earlier revisions showed you were referring to _"BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_for_quantity"_.  Either change your code to use `new Icheck_for_quantity("BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_for_quantity")` or add a new `<endpoint>` with `name=""`

Comment: If i change my code to _new check_for_quantity("BasicHttpBinding_Icheck_for_quantity")_ then the last photo appears. About the hosting part i have made a web form inside the same solution and then i run the site with right click -> run in browser and i have inserted the code into a button. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot btw guys for the great effort and time you have spent on this. Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: No problem.  I see you mention **output.config**.  By default, your project won't use that.  Instead, ensure your project's **web.config** contains everything within the `<system.serviceModel> ...</system.serviceModel>` block as listed in **output.config** - particulary the `<bindings>` and `<client>`.  Most likely you will need to merge that in. Ensure you don't accidentally wipe out any prior `<system.serviceModel>` that defines the `<services>` block.  _[Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731354(v=vs.110).aspx)_.  I hope this helps